# Clean PVC Facias and guttering

Tags: cleaning

I have been given the task of cleaning the front of our new home and it looks like they have never been wiped down before as there is a build up of all kinds of grime.

The parts which need a good clean are mostly PVC; Door, window frames, guttering, etc..

what would be a good way to clean them quickly?

Comment: Since you're asking essentially how to clean the outside of your house, I would suggest asking this question on a site like [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I assumed asking how to do it quickly would be a lifehack.

Comment: Terry, If the question was (for example) a question about how you were cleaning your house and you ran into an unusual problem that needed a good dose of thinking outside the box to overcome, I would tend to agree with you. But this looks like a *how-to* question for a site like Home Improvement, and adding that you would like to do the task quickly and efficiently doesn't really make it a life hack in the context of this site. It's an interesting question; it's just not a good fit for *this* site.

Answer (score 2):

I cleaned one wall of a friends house once which was covered in PVC Facia, and the only thing we used was a water high-pressure cleaner.  This worked like a charm, but do **not** have the beam too close to the panels as it might break it if it is old, fragile and crispy as these panels can be.